# Change password with Autofill support

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Autofill/save password function has been already implemented and working on login view.
I want to have a change password function, which also supports the autofill/strong password suggestion and replaces the old password in the keychain.

I already tried almost everything, but the OS doesn't replace the password nor showing any confirm alert about the change.
On the view there are 3 inputs: oldPassword, newPassword, confirmPassword in this order. The needed contentTypes and properties are set (.password,.newPassword,.newPassword), on viewWillDisappear I clear all the fields.
I also placed an inputfield with the username prefilled and made it "hidden", just to make sure the Apple's heuristic algorithm recognize what's the deal.

Autofill works on the oldPassword (fills the current password from keychain), the strong password suggestion also works and fills the newPassword and confirmPassword inputs.
However if I change the password and navigates from the view, nothing happens.

Is there anyhting am I missing? My head is already spinning from this "amazing" heuristic feature, so I cannot tell the OS when I need to use this function or trigger it somehow.
Debugging is also impossible.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround, but it's a little bit sketchy so I still curious about the right solution.

After the confirmation of the password is changed on the backend, I copy the newPassword's text into oldPassword's input.
After that I call popViewController/whatever to dismiss view and in the viewDidDisappear clear all fields.
With this trick the OS shows alert to update password in keychain.
If you choose to use the strong password suggestion it updates the password without any notice.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are hiding the username UITextField.
The username UITextField can be read-only, but it must be visibile on your view in order to have the heuristic working properly.

See https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/204/ at 14:30.